# Find $f \in C[a,b]$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ in sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $C[a,b]$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ a convergent series of positive numbers such that
$$||f_{k+1} - f_k||_{max} \leq a_k \ for \ all \ k$$ Prove that 
$$|f_{n+k}(x) -f_k(x) |\leq ||f_{n+k} -f_k ||_{max} \leq \sum\limits_{j=n}^{\infty} a_j$$ for all $k,n$ and all $x \in [a,b]$.
Conclude that there is a function $f \in C[a,b]$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ 
Use first part to show that $C[a, b]$, normed by the maximum norm, is a Banach space

**Here is my attempt:**

Since $||f_{k+1} - f_k||_{max} \leq a_k \ for \ all \ k$, we have 
$$f_{n+k}- f_k =\sum\limits_{j=n}^{n+k-1}[f_{j+1} -f_j] \ for \ all \ n, k$$
$$|f_{n+k} -f_k | \leq \max\limits_{x \in [a,b]} |f_{n+k} -f_n| $$
$$= ||f_{n+k} -f_n||_{max} \leq \sum\limits_{j=n}^{n+k-1} ||f_{j+1} -f_j||_{max} \leq \sum\limits_{j=n}^{\infty} a_j \ for \ all \ n,k$$
Therefore 
$$|f_{n+k}(x) -f_k(x) |\leq ||f_{n+k} -f_k ||_{max} \leq \sum\limits_{j=n}^{\infty} a_j$$ for all $k,n$ and all $x \in [a,b]$.

This tells me that $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the sup 
norm and so converge uniformly to functions  a function $f$ in $C([a,b])$ (I am not confident in this statement)
Am i correct, and how do i do the last part(prove that is Banach space)

Comment: Not quite, unfortunately: the conclusion that you are not confident about is based precisely on the assumption that $C([a,b])$ is topologically complete, so it is a Banach space, which is precisely the second part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in [a,b]$. Note that $| f _{n+p} (x) - f _n (x) | \le \sum \limits _{i=p} ^\infty a_i$, so the sequence of numbers $(f_n (x) ) _n$ is Cauchy, so it must have a limit that we shall call $f(x)$ (the reasoning is essentially like the one you have constructed yourself).

Let us show that $x \mapsto f(x)$ is a continuous function. Pick $x \in [a,b]$. Then $$|f(y) - f(x)| = |f(y) - f_n (y) + f_n(y) - f_n (x) + f_n (x) - f(x)| \le |f(y) - f_n (y)| + |f_n (y) - f_n (x)| + |f_n (x) - f(x)| ;$$ for sufficiently large $n$, the first and third terms of the sum become small due to the convergence found in the paragraph above, and the middle one becomes small due to the continuity of the functions $f_n$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous.

To show that $C([a,b])$ is a Banach space show that it is a linear space, and then that $\| \cdot \|$ satisfies the properties of a norm on this space; finally, with the proof sketched above, this space will also be topologically complete, so it will be a Banach space.

Comment: i still need my first part of the prove correct?

Comment: @Lucas: As you can see, my proof is just a sketch, there are details missing (on purpose); in particular, I do not prove that $(f_n (x) )_n$ is Cauchy, and this is exactly where your proof fits in: the part of your argument up to where you say *"this tells me that $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence"*. Those details must be included in my proof in order to make it complete.

Comment: make sense, just wanted to make sure, thanks